# Overloading the indirection operator to match the subscript operator?

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

I am attempting to write a class that behaves similarly to std::set - in that the elements are all unique, and adding an element already in the set doesn't do anything - but, where the elements in the set are in a custom order like a std::vector, as opposed to being sorted numerically/alphabetically or being completely unsorted like a std::unordered_set.

The way I've done this is by using a std::vector and a std::map together in my class. I actually already have this working how I want, and now I'm just trying to figure out how to add some overloads to more conveniently access the elements.

Here is a minimal example of what I have so far, stripped down to the part relevant to the question:

```
template <typename ValueType, typename Comparer = std::less<ValueType>> class MappedVector {
    public:
    using VECTOR = std::vector<ValueType>;

    private:
    VECTOR _vector = {};

    public:
    VECTOR get() const {
        return _vector;
    }

    ValueType operator[](ptrdiff_t index) const {
        return get()[index];
    }
};
```

The get method allows accessing the underlying std::vector, and the subscript operator allows accessing the elements.

I don't want other code to have direct access to the std::vector, because directly adding elements to it would cause it to become out of sync with the std::map I'm using to index it, so the use of `VECTOR` instead of `VECTOR&` and `ValueType` instead of `ValueType&` is intentional here: I want to return copies from these and to require going through my `push` and `pop` methods or assignment operator to modify the elements. (**EDIT:** I've since rewritten my class to fix this limitation as per the comments, but the main crux of my question is still relevant.)

Anyway, this all works fine. The issue is with the indirection operator. Typically in C++ (unless the operations are overloaded differently) the following two lines of code are equivalent:

```
std::string element = vec[1];
element = *(vec + 1);
```

I've already implemented the former, but am scratching my head what overloads I need to use to get the latter. The following compiles:

```
ValueType operator*() const {
    return get()[0];
}
```

But this only allows access to the first element. So I can't add one to the pointer to get another element like in the code sample above. If I replace it with what I believe would be correct:

```
ValueType operator*() const {
    return *get();
}
```

Now I get this compile error:

> Error C2676 binary '+': 'MAPPED_VECTOR' does not define this operator
> or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

I'm lead to believe that I need to overload operators for ++ and -- for this to work, but how exactly do I forward those so they're operating on the vector, and not the `this` object itself? I don't want to actually do some version of `_vector++` on the vector in my class, because that will affect all future accesses and not just the current one. But the indirection operator, to my understanding, happens afterward, so do I need to stash the result of the addition/subtraction, somehow?

Comment: Your `get` function is probably a bad idea. And it's even worse in that it returns a *copy* of the vector instead of a reference.

Comment: a set with custom ordering is `std::set<T,your_custom_comparator>`

Comment: *Anyway, this all works fine* no it doesn’t. It is very inefficient.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I'm aware of comparators, that isn't what I'm after. I want the elements to be in the order I added them, like a std::vector maintaining the order of elements added with push_back. The contents of the elements are arbitrary, but the order they were inserted is what I want to keep track of. So it is like a std::vector with all unique elements, such that I don't need to iterate the entire vector on every insertion to check if the element is already in the vector. I'm optimizing for it to be changed a lot and not read very often.

Comment: ok, still a `std::set` can do that already https://godbolt.org/z/9T1c3jvWY. For convenience you can wrap it to hide the index

Comment: I hadn't considered using std::pair in that fashion. I'll change it to use that method instead. I think if I want to hide the index I'd still need to override the subscript operator either way though, so it doesn't detract from my main question.

Comment: Those two lines are not equivalent with a vector; the addition is invalid. Perhaps you're thinking about arrays?

Comment: @MarekR I was referring to operator*, which I thought _was_ the indirection operator. The table you linked refers to it as such (*a, under Precedence 3.) I wanted the behaviour of dereferencing to match that of using subscripts.

Comment: @molbdnilo whoops, yeah, you're right. I almost never use the latter syntax for anything, I just wanted to include it because I know they are typically similar so it seemed right to support both. So I assumed it'd work the same with vector as it would with a raw array because I've never actually done that on a vector, but I guess std::vector overrides it differently. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation being performed on your class is the addition operator as the error message say. I.e. the expression is primarily `vec + 1`.

So you need an `operator+` function that takes a `size_t` argument and returns a pointer to the wanted element:

```
ValueType const* operator+(size_t index) const
{
    return &_vector[index];
}
```

---

To adhere to the [commutative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) of the addition, you should also create a function which allows `1 + vec`:

```
template <typename ValueType, typename Comparer = std::less<ValueType>>
ValueType const* operator+(size_t index, MappedVector<ValueType, Comparer> const& vector)
{
    // Invoke the operator+(size_t) function
    return vector + index;
}
```

Comment: To default `Comparer` is useless, as it is deducible.